# PHP Session variables does not pass and cannot be read through 3rd page

Tags: php, session

I have a sample program that passes the inputs entered in the fields to a $_SESSION, then echos to a 3rd page. But it seems the inputs entered in the first page (index.php) does not echo, whereas in the 2nd page, it does. How do I fix that?

I also want to have a code that the inputs are destroyed with closed, that's why I have a `onunload="<?php session_destroy(); ?>"` in every `body` of my code.

index.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="" method="post" action="page1indexHandler.php" onunload="<?php session_destroy(); ?>">
            Check-in: <input type="text" name="check_in" placeholder="Check-in">
            Check-out: <input type="text" name="check_out" placeholder="Check-out">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="Proceed" value="Proceed">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

page1indexHandler.php code:

```
<?php  
session_start();
$_SESSION['check_in'] = $_POST['check_in'];
$_SESSION['check_out'] = $_POST['check_out'];
header("Location: register.php");
?>
```

register.php (second page) code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="" method="post" action="page2registerHandler.php" onunload="<?php session_destroy(); ?>">
            first name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
            last name : <input type="text" name="lastname">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="proceed" value="proceed">
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

output.php (just for echo / checking purposes) code:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['check_in'] . "<br>";
    echo $_SESSION['check_out'] . "<br>";
    echo $_SESSION['firstname'] . "<br>";
    echo $_SESSION['lastname'] . "<br>";
?>
```

Here is the output of the sample program:

```
Notice: Undefined index: check_in in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\kenny\output.php on line 3


Notice: Undefined index: check_out in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\kenny\output.php on line 4

John // I inputted this in the register.php code, it echoes
Doe // also this one
```

Comment: `onunload` works on a client side. So `session_destroy` always runs on page load.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: I see.. I tried removing them and it worked. Thanks! =) But I want to do something, for example, when the user closes the browser in the middle of inputting these forms, the completed ones would just be destroyed. How do I do that?

Comment: @Kenny what do you mean by 'completed ones'?

Comment: I mean, when I completed the `check in` and `check out ` input, then it proceeds, right? Then for example, I discontinued the `first name` and `last name` page and closed my browser.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming here that your code does indeed flow through from your index.php to the handler and straight on to the register form.

The problem is, your form pages **are destroying the sessions when they load**.
The PHP code inside your "onunload" event of the form is executed before the page is sent to the user. All PHP code is.

PHP is a server-side language, none of it is executed by the client. On the second page it works because it is not loading a page that immediately destroys the session.